# How to access parent window in dialog

Tags: python, gtk, quickly

I am using Quickly and created the main window and a dialog. In the main window I am setting access to database (u1db) in the finish_initializing method (self.db=...). After an action I open a dialog where I need access to the database.

I thought that I can use self.get_parent() in the dialog to get instance of the main window and access the database, but return value of the get_parent() is None.

My question is, how can I access the instance of the parent window in the dialog or perhaps where should I place the instance of the database wrapper?

Shortened code:

```
# GuitestWindow.py
class GuitestWindow(Window):

    def finish_initializing(self, builder):
        ...
        self.db = u1db.open(
            db_path,
            create=True
        )


    def on_addaccountbutton_clicked(self, widget):
        dialog = NewAccountDialog.NewAccountDialog(db=self.db)
        result = dialog.run()
        dialog.hide()



# NewAccountDialog.py
class NewAccountDialog(Gtk.Dialog):
    __gtype_name__ = "NewAccountDialog"

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print "__new__: %s : %s" % (args, kwargs)
        builder = get_builder('NewAccountDialog')
        new_object = builder.get_object('new_account_dialog')
        new_object.finish_initializing(builder)
        print "__new__ end"
        return new_object


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "__init__: %s : %s" % (args, kwargs)
        self.db = kwargs.get('db')
        super(NewAccountDialog, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print "__init__ end"
```

Result:

```
__new__: () : {'db': <u1db.backends.sqlite_backend.SQLitePartialExpandDatabase object at 0x1884f50>}
__init__: () : {}
__init__ end
__new__ end
__init__: () : {'db': <u1db.backends.sqlite_backend.SQLitePartialExpandDatabase object at 0x1884f50>}
__init__ end
```

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty simple, just pass your main window instance to your dialog :-).

```
    # ...
    dialog = NewAccountDialog.NewAccountDialog(self)
    # ...

class NewAccountDialog(Gtk.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, main):
        self.main = main
        # I can manage main now!
```

Comment: I updated the code. When I pass a parameter, __new__ is called once, __init__ two times but one time without the parametr I supplied.